# Ios Apple music style search

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently seeking a way to make the search functionality of the apple music search inside my app, I have searched on many websites and have been unable to find a out of the box solution for this and i don't know where to start.

The basic functionality of it is:

- User taps on search icon in navigation bar)
- Search appears with the search bar already focused and the keyboard already open with a cancel button to close the search

I can't really explain how the search appears but it's not a normal segue,the search bar slides down from the top whilst the rest of the view comes in from the bottom and fades in, it looks really cool and I feel like alot of IOS apps handle search this way.

[image: apple music search]

if anyone could point me in the right direction or walk through how this would be done I would be very grateful.

I am using swift by the way

Comment: Have you tried to look at UISearchController?